# Nabaztag alternatives?

Tags: continuous-integration, nabaztag

Are there some good alternatives for a [Nabaztag](http://www.nabaztag.com/en/index.html)? We want to get several of these, but they're not cheap.

Comment: What are you using these little guys for? (cute!)

Comment: @rlb, This is tagged "CI" - we're using them (well one of them for now) to monitor our continuous integration.

And people, please don't vote to close without a comment! (This behavior never fails to annoy me)

Answer (score 3):

Some alternatives:

- [Lava Lamps](http://pragmaticautomation.com/cgi-bin/pragauto.cgi/Monitor/Devices/BubbleBubbleBuildsInTrouble.rdoc)
- [Ambiant Orbs](http://www.ambientdevices.com/cat/orb/orborder.html)
- The mentioned [Tux droid](http://www.kysoh.com/)
- A build dashboard on a monitor or LDC (like Hudson's [Radiator View](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Radiator+View+Plugin) or [eXtreme Feedback Panel](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/eXtreme+Feedback+Panel+Plugin))

Also check the following questions:

- [What’s your Favorite Extreme Feedback Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303614/whats-your-favorite-extreme-feedback-device)
- [Any experience with a Continuous Integration Appliance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414117/any-experience-with-a-continuous-integration-appliance)
- [please recommend an *easy* to setup device for visually indicating Build Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443994/please-recommend-an-easy-to-setup-device-for-visually-indicating-build-status)

Bunnies, a build dashboard, Lava Lamps, they'll all do the job. But racing against the wax of lava lamps (as mentioned in one of the question above) is indeed fun :)

Answer (score 0):

the tux droid might be a good alternative: http://www.kysoh.com/

last time i checked it cost about half the price of a nabaztag.

Answer (score 0):

Just put our [**Parabuild's build dashboard**](http://www.viewtier.com/products/parabuild/screenshots/screen_shot_0_dashboard.htm) on a large LCD TV in the hallway and you will get a nice build radiator.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to use it for and how you want it to look.  But the Insignia™ - Infocast 3.5" Internet Media Display is down to $50.  It's based on the Chumby (another option to consider) and is software and hardware hackable. Info on the hardware is at http://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?p=1140